# Snowflake Stored Procedure While Function

Tags: sql, function, loops, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can i recreate a while function in snowflake example:

```sql
WHILE @counter <= @LastRow
     BEGIN
        SELECT @DateLoad = CONVERT (date, SUNDAY)
        FROM [Staging].[Stg_EC_WeeksLoad]
        WHERE SEQUENCE = @counter;

        EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[pETLFillFact_Demographics_History] @Date = @DateLoad;

        SET @counter = @counter + 1;
    END
```

Comment: I recommend looking into Javascript Stored Procedures for something like that in Snowflake.

Comment: What have you tried sofar?

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake supports [expressing stored procedures in `JavaScript`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html), and `JavaScript` supports [multiple looping constructs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#while_statement) including `while (condition)`.

A rough translation of the described logic as a Snowflake procedure would appear as follows:

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE looping_process()
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
  // Get 'LastRow' dynamically, or set/pass a constant alternatively
  var row_count_query = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: "SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE" });
  var _resultSet = row_count_query.execute();
  var LastRow = row_count_query.getRowCount();

  var counter = 0;
  while (counter <= LastRow) {

    // Get the dynamic date value by applying the counter
    var seq_query = `SELECT SUNDAY::DATE AS "DateLoad" FROM "Staging"."Stg_EC_WeeksLoad" WHERE SEQUENCE = $counter`;
    var seq_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: seq_query });
    var seq_result = seq_stmt.execute(); seq_result.next();
    var DateLoad = seq_result.getColumnValue("DateLoad");

    // Construct and run the nested procedure call with value found above
    var sub_call_query = `CALL "dbo"."pETLFillFact_Demographics_History"($DateLoad)`;
    var sub_call_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sub_call_query });
    var sub_call_result = sub_call_stmt.execute(); sub_call_stmt.next();
    var return_value = sub_call_result.getColumnValue(1);

    // Increment for the next loop
    counter += 1;
  }
  // (… add other omitted logic, to return/error-handle/etc. …)
$$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working with Loops](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html):

> Snowflake Scripting supports the following types of loops:
>
> - FOR
> - WHILE
> - REPEAT
> - LOOP

---

Query in question could be translated as:

```
DECLARE
  c1 CURSOR FOR select SUNDAY::date AS DateLoad 
                from Staging.Stg_EC_WeeksLoad order by SEQUENCE;
BEGIN
  FOR record IN c1 DO
    CALL pETLFillFact_Demographics_History(record.DateLoad);
  END FOR;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

An example of the WHILE specific syntax (from the Snowflake docs) looks like this:

```
while (condition)  {
   // Do something ...
   }
```

Comment: Do you have a link to that in the documentation?

Comment: @MikeWalton I think I just summarised it from an example in the docs here (2. create the stored procedure): https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#using-result-scan-to-retrieve-the-result-from-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Ah, ok.  To be clear, that's a Javascript WHILE function, not a Snowflake SQL function.  Your answer seemed to indicate it was a Snowflake function, since the OP is showing what appears to be a SQL Server function that does have native SQL WHILE function.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks @MikeWalton for pointing this out. And yes, it was meant to be an example of a while loop in Snowflake's Javascript Stored Procedures (with these being suggested as the best solution to the original question)