# A SQL while loop code in Snowflake does not work

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake (but with a lot of SQL experience in SQL Server and BigQuery), and I am trying to create a While loop script.

The script raises an error that I can't fix because when I check the official documentation everything looks legit syntax-wise. here is the error I get and the script.

At first, I just generate sample data and create the tables, the loop itself starts on row number 98.

If someone could help me It would be great, thanks a lot.

The error :

> Syntax error: unexpected '('. (line 102)
> Syntax error line 7 at position 8 unexpected 'SELECT'. (line 102)

I have created a database named `temp_db` and inserted the data into temp tables.

The code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_db.public.tbl_workers
AS
SELECT worker_id, worker_name, worker_dob, worker_title, department, manager, Salary 
FROM (
VALUES  ('02B06EEE', 'Idona Z. Morrison', '19970908', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '53A3EB61', 6523)
, ('03339B30', 'Angelica Hicks', '19930920', 'Customer Relationship Manager', 'Customer Relationship', 'pCF469A0', 16490)
, ('0500B400', 'Caesar Q. Walter', '19900214', 'Staffing Coordinator', 'Human Resources', 'EDF53F0C', 11000)
, ('06669B60', 'Cedric Mckenzie', '19910930', 'Transfers Specialist', 'Back Office', '87264Z22', 6300)
, ('088D77AA', 'Kuame Ashley', '19831021', 'Receptionist', 'Headquarters', 'tt7E4y55', 6300)
, ('124DE17F', 'George G. Warner', '19971216', 'Legal Counsel', 'Legal', '62y2yF4F', 22985)
, ('124yE17F', 'Hop Church', '19630207', 'Chief creative officer', 'Management', '62y2yF4F', 38900)
, ('182FBE76', 'Karyn Ryan', '19710508', 'Intern', 'Sales', '96EF1725', 7460)
, ('193B6A1D', 'Kadeem Norman', '19930826', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '519211D3', 6405)
, ('196B6Z1Z', 'Rahim Hess', '19911010', 'Deposits Specialist', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 8500)
, ('275ED6C4', 'Octavius K. Franco', '19831229', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '519211D3', 6400)
, ('279EZ6C4', 'Hedy Odonnell', '19880111', 'Tester', 'QA', '919211Z6', 11040)
, ('2E618FB3', 'Timothy Dillon', '20001216', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '53A3EB61', 6400)
, ('2E618FB6', 'Dorian Norris', '19910115', 'Deposits Specialist', 'Back Office', '196B6Z1Z', 6000)
, ('32C2CF4F', 'Kylynn Calderon', '19840730', 'Clerk', 'Headquarters', 'tt7E4y55', 5400)
, ('33963B93', 'Erica I. Roberson', '19880119', 'Programmer', 'Technology', 'BCF469A0', 22369)
, ('3DB15457', 'Lydia Hogan', '19590718', 'Sales Agent', 'Sales', '73B70CE5', 22460)
, ('41666EEF', 'Farrah Rodgers', '19600612', 'Chief operating officer', 'Management', '62y2yF4F', 40100)
, ('4D2BCBBF', 'Hermione Q. Bowers', '19850804', 'DBA', 'Technology', 'pCF469A0', 23500)
, ('4D2pCppF', 'Kaseem Saunders', '19891101', 'Commercial Junior', 'Headquarters', 'E56E232C', 8000)
, ('4Z2BCBBF', 'Jeremy Cote', '19830101', 'Withdraws Specialist', 'Back Office', '9FZC9897', 6901)
, ('519211D3', 'Kennan Dejesus', '19871009', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '03339B30', 10123)
, ('52864CD0', 'Tyler Murray', '19890103', 'IT Support ', 'Technology', '87264D22', 8500)
, ('53A3EB61', 'Ronan Hicks', '19940629', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '03339B30', 9846)
, ('58DD1EFF', 'Kevin Mcdowell', '19930826', 'Clerk', 'Headquarters', 'tt7E4y55', 5200)
, ('58yy1EFF', 'Bruno Hansen', '19760107', 'Chief Technology Officer', 'Management', '62y2yF4F', 49640)
, ('611673FE', 'Craig T. Sargent', '19860914', 'Receptionist', 'Headquarters', '088D77AA', 5931)
, ('62y2yF4F', 'Elmo H. Stark', '19660729', 'Chief executive officer', 'Management', NULL, 64020)
, ('66966B96', 'Randall Houston', '19830919', 'Project Manager', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 18500)
, ('670D11D6', 'Oliver Graham', '19870104', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '519211D3', 5986)
, ('670Z11Z6', 'Rebekah K. Berry', '19881005', 'Deposits Specialist', 'Back Office', '196B6Z1Z', 6000)
, ('73B70CE5', 'Gisela Z. Mercado', '19891101', 'Sales Manager', 'Sales', '62y2yF4F', 21630)
, ('73B7PCE9', 'Zigi Zag', '20060407', 'Cyber Specialist', 'Technology', '58yy1EFF', 500)
, ('870W10DQ', 'Jasmine Cote', '20070122', 'Cyber Specialist', 'Technology', '58yy1EFF', 700)
, ('87264D22', 'Basil F. Becker', '19900227', 'Controller', 'Finance', 'E56E262y', 21097)
, ('87264Z22', 'Brent V. Day', '19810313', 'Transfers Specialist', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 8704)
, ('8F182FD6', 'Gregory X. Rhodes', '19860625', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '53A3EB61', 6400)
, ('8F182FZ6', 'Quinn P. Patton', '19830510', 'Tester', 'QA', '919211Z6', 12000)
, ('911E3E0C', 'Sarah W. Fulton', '19700429', 'Logistics Planner', 'Headquarters', '41666EEF', 12000)
, ('911E6E0y', 'Quamar L. Rodriquez', '19850813', 'Back Office Manager', 'Back Office', '41666EEF', 20647)
, ('919211Z6', 'Vaughan Albert', '19891101', 'QA Manager', 'QA', '58yy1EFF', 18463)
, ('92864CZ0', 'Catherine Banks', '19850418', 'Transfers Specialist', 'Back Office', '87264Z22', 6320)
, ('937D21AD', 'Zoe G. Silva', '19750429', 'IT Support ', 'Technology', '87264D22', 8500)
, ('967Z21ZZ', 'Shea R. Cunningham', '19840801', 'Transfers Specialist', 'Back Office', '87264Z22', 6320)
, ('96EF1725', 'Lila X. Cervantes', '19981007', 'Sales Agent', 'Sales', '73B70CE5', 20600)
, ('96Z6EB61', 'Hashim Smith', '19900228', 'Programmer', 'Technology', 'BCF469A0', 19880)
, ('990CBA12', 'Nigel Q. Hawkins', '19710206', 'Accountant', 'Finance', 'B3C14522', 11500)
, ('9FAC9857', 'Zane Jordan', '19910103', 'Programmer', 'Technology', 'BCF469A0', 20960)
, ('9FZC9897', 'Jasmine Mullen', '19780105', 'Withdraws Specialist', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 8700)
, ('AA7E4C55', 'Hashim Smith', '19820103', 'Management Analyst', 'Headquarters', '41666EEF', 17000)
, ('B3C14522', 'Macy P. Ramsey', '19831005', 'Senior Accountant', 'Finance', '87264D22', 15000)
, ('BCF469A0', 'Norman N. Stuart', '19970216', 'Senior Programmer', 'Technology', '58yy1EFF', 33050)
, ('BCF469Z0', 'Cally Z. West', '19831011', 'Withdraws Specialist', 'Back Office', '9FZC9897', 6480)
, ('C418AB87', 'Halee K. Warner', '19980122', 'Job Recruiter', 'Human Resources', 'EDF53F0C', 9500)
, ('DEC56B53', 'Brody Q. Nielsen', '19810615', 'Accountant', 'Finance', 'B3C14522', 12600)
, ('E56E232C', 'Vaughan Albert', '19871111', 'Commercial Specialist', 'Headquarters', '124yE17F', 19460)
, ('E56E262y', 'Maisie N. Strickland', '19620427', 'Chief financial officer', 'Finance', '62y2yF4F', 45200)
, ('EB5CC983', 'Dennis U. Valdez', '19860615', 'Job Recruiter', 'Human Resources', 'EDF53F0C', 9000)
, ('EDF53F0C', 'Emerson D. Ramos', '19800204', 'HR Manager', 'Human Resources', '41666EEF', 18000)
, ('EyF56F0y', 'Alika B. Shields', '19800818', 'Project Manager', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 19306)
, ('FCEFAF9B', 'Gareth Acevedo', '19690313', 'Accountant', 'Finance', '87264D22', 11500)
, ('pCF469A0', 'Glenna Fernandez', '19841218', 'Chief information officer', 'Management', '58yy1EFF', 40200)
, ('tt7E4y55', 'Samantha Sykes', '19611014', 'Administrative Manager', 'Headquarters', '41666EEF', 10060)
) AS t (worker_id, worker_name, worker_dob, worker_title, department, manager, Salary)
;
```

```
-- check the data
SELECT *
FROM temp_db.public.tbl_workers;

-- create the target table and insert the first level into it
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_db.public.tbl_workers_rc_results_op2
(
    worker_id string,
    worker_name string,
    worker_title string,
    department string,
    manager string,
    manager_name string,
    manager_title string,
    org_lvl int
);

INSERT INTO temp_db.public.tbl_workers_rc_results_op2
SELECT worker_id, worker_name, worker_title, department, manager
    , CAST(NULL AS string) AS manager_name
    , CAST(NULL AS string) AS manager_title, 1 AS org_lvl
FROM temp_db.public.tbl_workers
WHERE manager IS NULL;

-- the loop
BEGIN
    LET lvl := 1;
    LET flag := FALSE;
    
    WHILE (1 = 1) DO 
        SELECT TRUE INTO :flag
        FROM temp_db.public.tbl_workers_rc_results_op2 m 
        JOIN temp_db.public.tbl_workers e ON m.worker_id = e.manager
        WHERE m.org_lvl = :lvl
        LIMIT 1;
        
        IF (flag = FALSE) THEN 
             BREAK OUTER; 
        END IF;

        INSERT temp_db.public.tbl_workers_rc_results_op2
        SELECT e.worker_id, e.worker_name, e.worker_title, e.department
            , e.manager 
            , m.worker_name AS manager_name, m.worker_title AS manager_title
            , m.org_lvl + 1 AS org_lvl
        FROM temp_db.public.tbl_workers_rc_results_op2 m 
        JOIN temp_db.public.tbl_workers e ON m.worker_id = e.manager 
        WHERE m.org_level = :lvl;
        
        lvl := lvl + 1;
        flag = False;
    END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: Are you sure we are talking about Snowflake? Your code looks like Oracle PL/SQL to me. In Snowflake you can write while loops inside stored procedures, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904808/snowflake-stored-procedure-while-function).

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html#while-loop according to the documentation it is possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This can be written as a [recursive CTE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html). Albeit not what it turns out this question is wanting.

I have used a CTE for the `DATA` thus it looks messed up.

but as a full self contained blob:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM 
  VALUES  ('02B06EEE', 'Idona Z. Morrison', '19970908', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '53A3EB61', 6523)
    , ('03339B30', 'Angelica Hicks', '19930920', 'Customer Relationship Manager', 'Customer Relationship', 'pCF469A0', 16490)
    , ('0500B400', 'Caesar Q. Walter', '19900214', 'Staffing Coordinator', 'Human Resources', 'EDF53F0C', 11000)
    , ('06669B60', 'Cedric Mckenzie', '19910930', 'Transfers Specialist', 'Back Office', '87264Z22', 6300)
    , ('088D77AA', 'Kuame Ashley', '19831021', 'Receptionist', 'Headquarters', 'tt7E4y55', 6300)
    , ('124DE17F', 'George G. Warner', '19971216', 'Legal Counsel', 'Legal', '62y2yF4F', 22985)
    , ('124yE17F', 'Hop Church', '19630207', 'Chief creative officer', 'Management', '62y2yF4F', 38900)
    , ('182FBE76', 'Karyn Ryan', '19710508', 'Intern', 'Sales', '96EF1725', 7460)
    , ('193B6A1D', 'Kadeem Norman', '19930826', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '519211D3', 6405)
    , ('196B6Z1Z', 'Rahim Hess', '19911010', 'Deposits Specialist', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 8500)
    , ('275ED6C4', 'Octavius K. Franco', '19831229', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '519211D3', 6400)
    , ('279EZ6C4', 'Hedy Odonnell', '19880111', 'Tester', 'QA', '919211Z6', 11040)
    , ('2E618FB3', 'Timothy Dillon', '20001216', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '53A3EB61', 6400)
    , ('2E618FB6', 'Dorian Norris', '19910115', 'Deposits Specialist', 'Back Office', '196B6Z1Z', 6000)
    , ('32C2CF4F', 'Kylynn Calderon', '19840730', 'Clerk', 'Headquarters', 'tt7E4y55', 5400)
    , ('33963B93', 'Erica I. Roberson', '19880119', 'Programmer', 'Technology', 'BCF469A0', 22369)
    , ('3DB15457', 'Lydia Hogan', '19590718', 'Sales Agent', 'Sales', '73B70CE5', 22460)
    , ('41666EEF', 'Farrah Rodgers', '19600612', 'Chief operating officer', 'Management', '62y2yF4F', 40100)
    , ('4D2BCBBF', 'Hermione Q. Bowers', '19850804', 'DBA', 'Technology', 'pCF469A0', 23500)
    , ('4D2pCppF', 'Kaseem Saunders', '19891101', 'Commercial Junior', 'Headquarters', 'E56E232C', 8000)
    , ('4Z2BCBBF', 'Jeremy Cote', '19830101', 'Withdraws Specialist', 'Back Office', '9FZC9897', 6901)
    , ('519211D3', 'Kennan Dejesus', '19871009', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '03339B30', 10123)
    , ('52864CD0', 'Tyler Murray', '19890103', 'IT Support ', 'Technology', '87264D22', 8500)
    , ('53A3EB61', 'Ronan Hicks', '19940629', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '03339B30', 9846)
    , ('58DD1EFF', 'Kevin Mcdowell', '19930826', 'Clerk', 'Headquarters', 'tt7E4y55', 5200)
    , ('58yy1EFF', 'Bruno Hansen', '19760107', 'Chief Technology Officer', 'Management', '62y2yF4F', 49640)
    , ('611673FE', 'Craig T. Sargent', '19860914', 'Receptionist', 'Headquarters', '088D77AA', 5931)
    , ('62y2yF4F', 'Elmo H. Stark', '19660729', 'Chief executive officer', 'Management', NULL, 64020)
    , ('66966B96', 'Randall Houston', '19830919', 'Project Manager', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 18500)
    , ('670D11D6', 'Oliver Graham', '19870104', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '519211D3', 5986)
    , ('670Z11Z6', 'Rebekah K. Berry', '19881005', 'Deposits Specialist', 'Back Office', '196B6Z1Z', 6000)
    , ('73B70CE5', 'Gisela Z. Mercado', '19891101', 'Sales Manager', 'Sales', '62y2yF4F', 21630)
    , ('73B7PCE9', 'Zigi Zag', '20060407', 'Cyber Specialist', 'Technology', '58yy1EFF', 500)
    , ('870W10DQ', 'Jasmine Cote', '20070122', 'Cyber Specialist', 'Technology', '58yy1EFF', 700)
    , ('87264D22', 'Basil F. Becker', '19900227', 'Controller', 'Finance', 'E56E262y', 21097)
    , ('87264Z22', 'Brent V. Day', '19810313', 'Transfers Specialist', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 8704)
    , ('8F182FD6', 'Gregory X. Rhodes', '19860625', 'Customer Service Representative', 'Customer Relationship', '53A3EB61', 6400)
    , ('8F182FZ6', 'Quinn P. Patton', '19830510', 'Tester', 'QA', '919211Z6', 12000)
    , ('911E3E0C', 'Sarah W. Fulton', '19700429', 'Logistics Planner', 'Headquarters', '41666EEF', 12000)
    , ('911E6E0y', 'Quamar L. Rodriquez', '19850813', 'Back Office Manager', 'Back Office', '41666EEF', 20647)
    , ('919211Z6', 'Vaughan Albert', '19891101', 'QA Manager', 'QA', '58yy1EFF', 18463)
    , ('92864CZ0', 'Catherine Banks', '19850418', 'Transfers Specialist', 'Back Office', '87264Z22', 6320)
    , ('937D21AD', 'Zoe G. Silva', '19750429', 'IT Support ', 'Technology', '87264D22', 8500)
    , ('967Z21ZZ', 'Shea R. Cunningham', '19840801', 'Transfers Specialist', 'Back Office', '87264Z22', 6320)
    , ('96EF1725', 'Lila X. Cervantes', '19981007', 'Sales Agent', 'Sales', '73B70CE5', 20600)
    , ('96Z6EB61', 'Hashim Smith', '19900228', 'Programmer', 'Technology', 'BCF469A0', 19880)
    , ('990CBA12', 'Nigel Q. Hawkins', '19710206', 'Accountant', 'Finance', 'B3C14522', 11500)
    , ('9FAC9857', 'Zane Jordan', '19910103', 'Programmer', 'Technology', 'BCF469A0', 20960)
    , ('9FZC9897', 'Jasmine Mullen', '19780105', 'Withdraws Specialist', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 8700)
    , ('AA7E4C55', 'Hashim Smith', '19820103', 'Management Analyst', 'Headquarters', '41666EEF', 17000)
    , ('B3C14522', 'Macy P. Ramsey', '19831005', 'Senior Accountant', 'Finance', '87264D22', 15000)
    , ('BCF469A0', 'Norman N. Stuart', '19970216', 'Senior Programmer', 'Technology', '58yy1EFF', 33050)
    , ('BCF469Z0', 'Cally Z. West', '19831011', 'Withdraws Specialist', 'Back Office', '9FZC9897', 6480)
    , ('C418AB87', 'Halee K. Warner', '19980122', 'Job Recruiter', 'Human Resources', 'EDF53F0C', 9500)
    , ('DEC56B53', 'Brody Q. Nielsen', '19810615', 'Accountant', 'Finance', 'B3C14522', 12600)
    , ('E56E232C', 'Vaughan Albert', '19871111', 'Commercial Specialist', 'Headquarters', '124yE17F', 19460)
    , ('E56E262y', 'Maisie N. Strickland', '19620427', 'Chief financial officer', 'Finance', '62y2yF4F', 45200)
    , ('EB5CC983', 'Dennis U. Valdez', '19860615', 'Job Recruiter', 'Human Resources', 'EDF53F0C', 9000)
    , ('EDF53F0C', 'Emerson D. Ramos', '19800204', 'HR Manager', 'Human Resources', '41666EEF', 18000)
    , ('EyF56F0y', 'Alika B. Shields', '19800818', 'Project Manager', 'Back Office', '911E6E0y', 19306)
    , ('FCEFAF9B', 'Gareth Acevedo', '19690313', 'Accountant', 'Finance', '87264D22', 11500)
    , ('pCF469A0', 'Glenna Fernandez', '19841218', 'Chief information officer', 'Management', '58yy1EFF', 40200)
    , ('tt7E4y55', 'Samantha Sykes', '19611014', 'Administrative Manager', 'Headquarters', '41666EEF', 10060)
  t (worker_id, worker_name, worker_dob, worker_title, department, manager, Salary)
)
SELECT * FROM (
    WITH RECURSIVE hi_cte AS (
          SELECT 
                worker_id, 
                worker_name,
                worker_title,
                department,
                manager, 
                NULL::text AS manager_name,
                NULL::text AS manager_title,
                1 AS org_lvl
          FROM data
          WHERE manager IS NULL
      
          UNION ALL
      
          SELECT e.worker_id,
                 e.worker_name, 
                 e.worker_title, 
                 e.department,
                 e.manager,
                 m.worker_name AS manager_name, 
                 m.worker_title AS manager_title,
                 m.org_lvl + 1 AS org_lvl
            FROM hi_cte m 
            JOIN data e 
                ON m.worker_id = e.manager
    )
    select * from hi_cte
)
;
```

gives (trimmed):

| WORKER_ID | WORKER_NAME | WORKER_TITLE | DEPARTMENT | MANAGER | MANAGER_NAME | MANAGER_TITLE | ORG_LVL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 62y2yF4F | Elmo H. Stark | Chief executive officer | Management |  |  |  | 1 |
| 124DE17F | George G. Warner | Legal Counsel | Legal | 62y2yF4F | Elmo H. Stark | Chief executive officer | 2 |
| 124yE17F | Hop Church | Chief creative officer | Management | 62y2yF4F | Elmo H. Stark | Chief executive officer | 2 |
| 41666EEF | Farrah Rodgers | Chief operating officer | Management | 62y2yF4F | Elmo H. Stark | Chief executive officer | 2 |
| 58yy1EFF | Bruno Hansen | Chief Technology Officer | Management | 62y2yF4F | Elmo H. Stark | Chief executive officer | 2 |
| 73B70CE5 | Gisela Z. Mercado | Sales Manager | Sales | 62y2yF4F | Elmo H. Stark | Chief executive officer | 2 |
| E56E262y | Maisie N. Strickland | Chief financial officer | Finance | 62y2yF4F | Elmo H. Stark | Chief executive officer | 2 |
| E56E232C | Vaughan Albert | Commercial Specialist | Headquarters | 124yE17F | Hop Church | Chief creative officer | 3 |
| 911E3E0C | Sarah W. Fulton | Logistics Planner | Headquarters | 41666EEF | Farrah Rodgers | Chief operating officer | 3 |
| 911E6E0y | Quamar L. Rodriquez | Back Office Manager | Back Office | 41666EEF | Farrah Rodgers | Chief operating officer | 3 |
| AA7E4C55 | Hashim Smith | Management Analyst | Headquarters | 41666EEF | Farrah Rodgers | Chief operating officer | 3 |

but if you have a table, replace `data` and use:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hi_cte AS (
      SELECT 
            worker_id, 
            worker_name,
            worker_title,
            department,
            manager, 
            NULL::text AS manager_name,
            NULL::text AS manager_title,
            1 AS org_lvl
      FROM data
      WHERE manager IS NULL
  
      UNION ALL
  
      SELECT e.worker_id,
             e.worker_name, 
             e.worker_title, 
             e.department,
             e.manager,
             m.worker_name AS manager_name, 
             m.worker_title AS manager_title,
             m.org_lvl + 1 AS org_lvl
        FROM hi_cte m 
        JOIN data e 
            ON m.worker_id = e.manager
)
select * from hi_cte
```

and then you can do inserts, or what ever you please.

Comment: thank you, Simeon. I know I can do it with a recursive CTE. I just to do it with a loop in order to families myself with it in the snowflake enviroment

Comment: @Michael_85 But this is snowflake, why use a indirect loop, when you can explain it to the engine, and have it do the work.

Comment: You are absolutely correct the right, easy, and efficient way is to use recursive CTE. I just want to familiarise myself with loops in the snowflake environment, that is why I am trying to do this with a loop

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I used Javascript to make it work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_db.public.p_workers_loop()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE javascript
AS 
$$  
    var _lvl  = 1;
    var _flag = 1;
    var _query;
    
    while (_flag == 1)
    {
    
        _query = snowflake.createStatement({
            sqlText: "SELECT 1 AS flag FROM temp_db.public.tbl_workers_rc_results_op2 m JOIN temp_db.public.tbl_workers e " +
            "ON m.worker_id = e.manager WHERE m.org_lvl = " + _lvl + " LIMIT 1;" 
        });
                
        _flag = _query.execute().getRowCount();
        
        _query = snowflake.createStatement({
            sqlText: "INSERT INTO temp_db.public.tbl_workers_rc_results_op2 " +
            "SELECT e.worker_id, e.worker_name, e.worker_title, e.department, e.manager, m.worker_name AS manager_name" +
            ", m.worker_title AS manager_title, m.org_lvl + 1 AS org_lvl " +
            "FROM temp_db.public.tbl_workers_rc_results_op2 m JOIN temp_db.public.tbl_workers e " +
            "ON m.worker_id = e.manager " + 
            "WHERE m.org_lvl = " + _lvl + ";"        
        });
                
        _query.execute();
            
        _lvl += 1;        
    }  
$$    
 
CALL temp_db.public.p_workers_loop();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Observations in your code :

1. You are using  org_level  column name wrong during second insert stmt  and using org_lvl for first time for table tbl_workers_rc_results_op2.
   2.BREAK OUTER keyword works for loop construct but not for while loop.
2. Your loop never exits because of flagging variable is always TRUE
   Below is code which works well and you can fine tune your logic in case .Please add "execute immediate $$" start of code below code and end with it "$$" to make below code work and change database name to validate.

> 

```
begin
  let lvl := 1;
  let flag := FALSE;
    loop
    SELECT TRUE INTO :flag    
        FROM  LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG.PUBLIC.TBL_WORKERS_RC_RESULTS_OP2 m  JOIN LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG.PUBLIC.TBL_WORKERS e ON m.worker_id = e.manager
        WHERE m.org_lvl = :lvl limit 1; 
        INSERT INTO
    LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG.PUBLIC.TBL_WORKERS_RC_RESULTS_OP2(
        worker_id,
        worker_name,
        worker_title,
        department,
        manager,
        manager_name,
        manager_title,
        org_lvl
    )
SELECT
    e.worker_id,
    e.worker_name,
    e.worker_title,
    e.department,
    e.manager,
    m.worker_name AS manager_name,
    m.worker_title AS manager_title,
    m.org_lvl + 1 AS org_lvl
FROM
   LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG.PUBLIC.TBL_WORKERS_RC_RESULTS_OP2 m
    JOIN LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG.PUBLIC.TBL_WORKERS e ON m.worker_id = e.manager
WHERE
    m.org_lvl = :lvl; 
    IF (flag = TRUE) THEN 
             break; 
        END IF;
 lvl := lvl + 1;
 flag := FALSE;
  end loop;
end;
```